# Gcd of Fibonacci and Catalan

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Let $F_n=1,1,2,3,5,\ldots$ (starting with $n=1$) be the Fibonacci sequence and let $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ be the Catalan sequence.
Define $B_z$ to be the cardinality of $$B_z := \#\bigl\{ n \leq z | \gcd(F_n,C_n)=1 \bigr\}.$$ 
It seems $$\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{B_z}{z}=\frac14.$$ 
Posted a related question here: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2131648/gcd-of-catalan-and-fibonacci-numbers, but it got no answer and, thinking a bit about it, the question might be more research related than elementary (but I have no real training in such questions).
So question is: Does $B_z/z$ converge, and if so, to what?
Here some values of $g_z := B_z/z$,
$$g_{1000}=\frac{71}{250}=0.284, 
\quad g_{2000}=\frac{13}{50}=0.260, 
\quad g_{3000}= \frac{187}{750}\approx0.249, 
\quad g_{4000}=\frac{979}{4000}\approx0.245.$$
The sequence of integers such that the gcd is one starts with $$1,2,3,4,5,8,10,11,13,14,17,22,23,25,\ldots$$ and is probably not known in the sequence database.

Comment: Are you assuming $F_0 = F_1 = 1$ or $F_1 = F_2 = 1$?

Comment: $F_1=F_2=1$.Long comment needed.

Comment: Yes -- in the stackexchange question there was confusion caused by the fact that if you re-index the Fibonacci sequence then this completely changes $B_z$. So perhaps why not list the first few $F_n$ and $C_n$, plus the first few $n$ such that the gcd is 1, so everyone knows we're talking about the same question.

Comment: No, I justed needed to add something because $F_1=F_2=1$ was too short for a comment.

Comment: No but honestly, put it into the question, so people can just read the MO question (and not the MO comments, or the SE question, or the SE comments etc) -- you will be more likely to get a response that way. In particular the first few $n$ such that the gcd is 1 will be a very useful thing to have in the question so that people know quickly if they have made a mistake.

Comment: Why is 14 in the sequence?  Is not the case that if k is missing from the sequence, so too is every multiple of k missing as well?  This should help with estimating the ratio.  Gerhard "At Least, Estimating From Above" Paseman, 2017.02.07.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman no, you are wrong. The 1/(n+1) in the definition of $C_n$ causes some divisors to get lost... I've just been looking at the pattern of the gcd's with indices mod, say, 84. For certain $k$'s mod 84, there are quite long sequences (e.g. length 35) of $i$'s such that $gcd(F_{k+84i},C_{k+84i})=1$ , but then there will be some i where it doesn't hold. I'd tend to believe that for any $k$, there will be eventually such an $i$, and this not only mod 84 but anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit overlong for a comment, and not really an answer, but includes some information about a related problem that might offer approaches to this one. In particular, the fact that the Fibonacci sequence is a divisibility sequence means that gcd properties involving $F_n$ are tied into properties for $F_m$ for $m\mid n$. So you might try looking at the proportion of primes in your set.

The Fibonacci sequence is a linear recursion and a divisibility sequence. For a similar question in which one takes two Fibonacci-type sequences, there are conjectures, but not even an inkling of a proof. For example, Ailon and Rudnick conjectured that $$\{n\ge1 : \gcd(2^n-1,3^n-1)=1\}$$ is infinite, and I published a somewhat dubious heuristic argument that $$\text{Density}\Bigl(\{p~\text{prime}:\gcd(2^p-1,3^p-1)=1\}\Bigr)=1.$$ (The density over all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ seems harder to guess.) More generally, due to the divisibility property of these sequences, for $a,b\ge2$ multiplicatively independent, it is natural to look at $$\{n\ge1 : \gcd(a^n-1,b^n-1)=\gcd(a-1,b-1)\}.$$ I'll also mention that Ailon and Rudnick proved a stronger version of their conjecture when one replaces the integers $a$ and $b$ with polynomials $a(T),b(T)\in\mathbb{C}[T]$.

Comment: There is a good reason that Joe Silverman brought in those gcd problems: for each prime $p$ there is smallest integer $\alpha(p)$ such that $\nu_p(F_{\alpha(p)})=1$. With this number, $\nu_p(F_{n\cdot\alpha(p)})=\nu_p((p+1)^n-1)$ and $\nu_p(F_m)=0$ (whenever $\alpha(p)$ does not divide $m$). Of course, $\nu_p((p+1)^n-1)=\nu_p(pn)$ but that is not my point. The intent is to indicate that $x^n-1$ enters the picture of divisibility of the Fibonacci number.